# UserControl opacity 0 but still clickable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I've got a UserControl which has an opacity of 0.
At that state it shouldn't be clickable.
How to disable/re-enable it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opacity doesn't disable hit testing.

You disable hit testing several ways:

1. The most obvious, set IsHitTestVisible=false on your UserControl
2. Change visibility to hidden instead of Opacity=0
3. Change Visibility to collapsed (NOTE: This will change the layout semantics, collapsed will NOT consume screen real estate so it is actually different behaviorally then Opacity=0)

Answer (score 0):

```
Visibility: Collapsed
```

Answer (score 0):

Set HitTestVisible to false.

Like below `this.IsHitTestVisible = false;`

HTH